# Difference in ServiceManifest for owin hosted API controller vs regular stateless service

Tags: service, azure-service-fabric, stateless

When you create owin hosted API controller in service fabric with vs 2015, the following line appears in the ServiceManifest.xml file (under Resources/Endpoints):

```
<Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8726" />
```

But in case of regular stateless service, the following line appears in the related ServiceManifest.xml file:

```
<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" />
```

Since both are stateless services under the hood, why the difference in Endpoint definition? What does this signify? Also how would I call the 2nd service (from 1st service) over http transport?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web API is normally used as a gateway to the application, so it requires a fixed port, to be mapped by the load balancer to an external port (in contrast to the default, a random port assigned by the Fabric).

In addition, this ensures a correct HTTP endpoint registration in Windows, as described in the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/):

> This step is important because the service host process runs under
>   restricted credentials (Network Service on Windows). This means that
>   your service won't have access to set up an HTTP endpoint on its own.
>   By using the endpoint configuration, Service Fabric knows to set up
>   the proper access control list (ACL) for the URL that the service will
>   listen on. Service Fabric also provides a standard place to configure
>   endpoints.

Comment: Can you answer the 2nd part of the question? How would I call the 2nd service (from 1st service) over http transport?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617556/optimized-http-service-invocation-with-in-azure-service-fabric